# Unable to query nVarChar(Max) field in Access 2010

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, nvarchar

have used Stack Overflow as a resource hundreds of times, but my first time posting a question for some help!

I've got a table in SQL Server 2005 which contains 4 nVarChar(Max) fields.
I'm trying to pull out the data from an Access (2010) VBA Module using ADO 2.8
I'm connecting using SQL driver SQLNCLI10

(I can't use a linked table, as the 'table' I will ultimately be querying is a Table-Valued Function)

When I then print / use the recordset, the data is getting jumbled and concatenated with other fields in the same record - with a bunch of obscure characters thrown in.

The VBA: (various other methods were tried with the same result)

```
Sub TestWithoutCasting()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Integer

cn.Open "Data Source=ART;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True;"

Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT * FROM JobDetail WHERE JobID = 2558 ORDER BY SeqNo ASC")

Do While Not rs.EOF

    For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name & ": " & rs.Fields(i).Value
    Next i

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Example Output:

```
SeqNo: 1
CommandID: 2
Parameter1:     2 Daily Report    é [& some other chars not showing on here]
Parameter2: [Null]
Parameter3: [Null]
Parameter4: [Null]
Description: Daily Report
Active: False
```

Expected Output:

```
SeqNo: 1
CommandID: 2
Parameter1: SELECT  Day_Number  ,Day_Text  ,Channel_Group_ID [...etc]
Parameter2: [Null]
Parameter3: [Null]
Parameter4: [Null]
Description: Daily Report
Active: False
```

So, it's grabbing bits of data from other fields instead of the correct data (in this case, it's an SQL statement)

I then tried casting the nvarchar(max) fields as text at source

View Created:

```
    CREATE VIEW TestWithCast 
    AS
    SELECT jd.JobID, jd.SeqNo, jd.CommandID
    ,cast(jd.Parameter1 as text) as Parameter1
    ,cast(jd.Parameter2 as text) as Parameter2
    ,cast(jd.Parameter3 as text) as Parameter3
    ,cast(jd.Parameter4 as text) as Parameter4
    ,jd.[Description]
    ,jd.Active

    FROM JobDetail jd
```

Now, I initially had some luck here - using the same code as above does bring back data - but when I use this code in my main code (which jumps in & out of other procedures); as soon as I've queried the first result of the recordset, it appears to wipe the rest of the records / fields, setting them to Null. I also tried setting the value of each field to a variable whilst the rest of the vba runs before getting the next record - but this doesn't help either.

It almost feels like I need to dump the recordset into a local Access table, and query from there - which is a bazaar workaround for what is already a workaround (by casting as text).

I there something I'm completely missing here, or do I indeed need to cast as text and load to a local table?

Thanks for any help - it's driving me mad!

ps. Hope I've given the right level of detail / info - please let me know if I missed anything key.

EDIT:

Yikes, I think I've done it / found the issue...
I changed the driver to SQLSRV32 (v6.01) - and seems to work fine directly against the text casted  field.
So... why would it work with an older driver but not the newer 'recommended' (by various sources I read) as the one to use.
And... will there be a significant drawback in using this over the native client?

EDIT 2:

Ok, I've tried a few drivers on a few machines, in each case with both the TEXT CASTING and Directly to VARCHAR MAX..

[On my windows 7 machine w/ SQLSMS 2008]

SQL Native Client 10.0 - Neither method works reliably with this driver
SQL Server 6.01 - BOTH methods appear to work reliably - further testing needed though

[On our production server w/ SQLS 2005]

SQL Native Client (v2005.90) - Does not work at all with varchar(max), but DOES work with text casting
SQL Server (v2008.86) - BOTH methods appear to work reliably - further testing needed though

This should make deployment interesting!

Comment: Worth a try: Stop using `SELECT *` ([you should stop doing that anyway](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx)), name your columns and name the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` last. This could be carryover from [similar problems with `TEXT/NTEXT` I wrote about many years ago](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-deal-with-memo-text-hyperlink-and-currency-columns.html).

Comment: Thanks Aaron - only used Select * for the example - not normally that sloppy! I did try playing around with the field order, but all 4 'Parameter' field are nvarchar(max) - with different ones being populated on each record - sometimes just 1 of them, sometimes all. (ps, interesting articles, thanks - having a read though them)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real answer, because I did not test it, but ... You are using a "DataTypeCompatibility=80" parameter in your connection.  As far as I know, DataTypeCompatibility=80 refers to SQL Server 2000, where the nvarchar(max) field type was still not implemented.

Comment: Ooh, good catch, read right past that. Also why are you using MARS?

Comment: If I don't include the DataType, it doesn't work at all - I get no data for that field. MARS prob not needed, I think it was in there when I first got it close to working, and never took off. Have now removed, but kept DataType

Comment: You could try a DataTypeCompatibility=90 (for a 2005 SQL Server), or even 100 (for a 2008 SQL Server), depending on your server.

Comment: Thanks Philippe, it hasn't changed the behaviour, but have updated to '90' in line with the database being used.

Comment: I have been requesting fields of such a type from a 2005 (and now 2008 )server through an SQLOLEDB connection (Provider=SQLOLEDB.1) without any problem for years.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved it by converting the field to an nvarchar(1000). Would be an easy, compatible solution for your problem if 1000 chars is enough.